# I have a php page with errors that i cant view

Tags: php, nginx

I am using nginx and php5 this is my php-fpm.conf file i cant seem to get page to the log errors. There is also a php.ini file I am not sure which to edit.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix (/usr). This prefix can be dynamically changed by using the
; '-p' argument from the command line.

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
; Relative path can also be used. They will be prefixed by:
;  - the global prefix if it's been set (-p argument)
;  - /usr otherwise
;include=/etc/php5/fpm/*.conf

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: none
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; in a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; The maximum number of processes FPM will fork. This has been design to control
; the global number of processes when using dynamic PM within a lot of pools.
; Use it with caution.
; Note: A value of 0 indicates no limit
; Default Value: 0
; process.max = 128

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the master process (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lower priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool process will inherit the master process priority
;         unless it specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
; process.priority = -19

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

; Set open file descriptor rlimit for the master process.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; - kqueue     (FreeBSD >= 4.1, OpenBSD >= 2.9, NetBSD >= 2.0)
; - /dev/poll  (Solaris >= 7)
; - port       (Solaris >= 10)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
;events.mechanism = epoll

; When FPM is build with systemd integration, specify the interval,
; in second, between health report notification to systemd.
; Set to 0 to disable.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default value: 10
;systemd_interval = 10

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Multiple pools of child processes may be started with different listening
; ports and different management options.  The name of the pool will be
; used in logs and stats. There is no limitation on the number of pools which
; FPM can handle. Your system will tell you anyway :)

; To configure the pools it is recommended to have one .conf file per
; pool in the following directory:
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf

; enable display of errors
    php_flag[display_errors] = on
    php_flag[display_startup_errors] = on
```

code for page that needs errors logged to apge or is having errors

```
<?php include 'Stripe.php'; ?>


<?php

ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account
Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_random");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email = $_POST["email"];


// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {

  $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $email,
    'card'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "cad",
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    "description" => "payinguser@example.com"

    )
  );



} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
  // This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client
  $message = "card declinded";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}

?>

<?php include 'head.php'; ?>
<body>

  <!--header-->
  <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

  <!--content-->
  <div class="global indent">
    <div class="container partner-wrap">

  <!--header-->

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">

  <h1>Your purchase is complete, here is your receipt, you should also recieve a email
    shortly with further details</h1>

  </div>

  </div>

  </div>
</div>


  <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/tm-scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the question here?  What's the problem?

Comment: SOrry I mispoke, i cant get the page to log errors.

Comment: And where is the code that generates the errors that you cant view? This is your configuration file and not your code.

Comment: it works locally, but i get a blank page on the server, by it works locally i mean the submission gets sent to stripe and no error occurs.

Comment: if you are getting blank page on the server, can you try to check the permissions of your file. Does your server have the permission to read that php file? Can you check that once & let us know?

Comment: also can you try putting `ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);` before, your include statement `<?php include 'Stripe.php'; ?>` , because, if in case there is any little possibility of that file having errors, then, your php script will die in the first line itself, and it will never reach the 6th line where you have `ini_set()` and therefore it will never display any errors.

Comment: The error I was getting if any was curious was not having curl installed for stripe php library,this fixed it sudo apt-get install php5-curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use php error reporting and init_set function to display errors in your php file, here is one example from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php),

```
<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

Comment: it won't be effective unless you set `display_errors = On`in your php.in file

Answer (score 0):

Add it on your php page right after `<?php`

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I have done that actually and that doesnt seem to work.